# How to modify Laravel Jetstream login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am using Larave Jetstream livewire and I want to modify the login.

login from having a hidden input field "is_admin" with an initial value of 1

when a user submits login form backend check with `is_admin` = 1 of the database table field

---

table structure:
name, email, password, is_admin

is_admin = 0 or 1

I want to check the is_admin flag, If provided credentials match `email`, `password`, and `is_admin=1` then only the user can log.

---

Comment: I think your way is wrong. You can use Laravel's policies or gates. Also, you can use spatie-permission package.

In your way, users can manipulate easily your system and they can log in as admin.

Please share more details from your code and DB structure.

By the way, you can watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsmGlPi43hk

Comment: What's the use of a **hidden** input field for this? A user can't change it so `is_admin` will always be 1

Answer (score 5):

I think you intend to customise authentication. Since you are using Jetstream most probably you are using Fortify out of the box (by default).

There are 2 ways. These are to help you sent extra data from your authentication form and not just the hidden field. However, if the is_admin field is default, then I don't think you should add it as hidden field. You could be compromised.

Example 1. Edit the User.php model and add a boot method
`Fortify::authenticateUsing`

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $is_admin = $request->is_admin ?? 1;

        // Your code here ... Example for login in below
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication

Example 2. Also you may edit the `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php`

And in the boot method add

```php
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request){
    $is_admin = $request->is_admin ?? 1;
    
    // Other codes here
});
```

Also unless I did not understand you correctly but just want to be sure the user is admin before allowing login, then you could tweak the auth code in `Example 1` to do that.

```php
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {

    $user = User::where(['email' => $request->email, 'is_admin' => 1])->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
    }
});
```